# Error com.google.android.gms: play-services: 15.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

quiero plantearles mi problema:

El `build.gradle` lo tengo así:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
...
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

Ahora me gustaria poder obtener latitud y longitud del usuario, para ello he leido que lo mejor es

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

El problema que al incorporar este servicio de google play me marca con errores las 2 anteriores. Y tengo un mapa funcionando con play-services-maps, y no se porque tambien me marca error el appcompat-v7

Cual podría ser el problema?

Estoy usando `Android Studio 3.2.1`

con esta configuración:

```
minSdkVersion 19

targetSdkVersion 27
```

GRACIAS !!!!

Comment: si usas las version 15.0.1 en los maps igualseria en los play services

Answer (score 0):

Para usar los mapas y geolocalización debes usar:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

---

referente a :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

en realidad no es un error, es un warning que indica debes usar una versión adecuada, aunque en realidad es una versión adecuada para :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Esto no afectara al funcionamiento de la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias tu comentario me sirvió mucho. Lo que me está sucediendo ahora es que no me está preguntando si quiero habilitar el Location, y por lo tanto no me devuelve la ubicación, ahora si lo habilito manualmente funciona.

Comment: Si te refieres a el permiso, cuando cambias a targetSdkVersion 27 y tu dispositivo tiene Android 6.0 o posterior, se tiene que requerir manualmente el permiso, no hay otra opción.